# SelfJoin using Symfony 1.4/propel 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, self-join

I need to do self join using Symfony 1.4/Propel 1.4. My tables/db are too big to put here but an example table is given below to replicate the issue I'm facing.

Consider following example table with example data

```
Table Employee
----------------------------------------
|id    | name                    | mid |
----------------------------------------
|1     | CEO                     |NULL |
|2     | CTO                     |1    |
|3     | CFO                     |1    |
|4     | PM1                     |2    |
|5     | TL1                     |4    |
----------------------------------------
```

Here first column is employee, second is employee name and 3rd is manager id. mid is link to another row in same table. For example, CTO(2) reports to CEO(1) so mid in second row is 1.

I need following output:

```
---------------------
|ename    | manager |
---------------------
|CTO      | CEO     |
|CFO      | CEO     |
|PM1      | CTO     |
|TL1      | PM1     |
---------------------
```

The SQL query will be:

```
SELECT e.name,m.name
FROM employee e, employee m
WHERE e.mid=m.id
AND e.mid NOT NULL;
```

My problem is, how do I write same query in Symfony/Propel 1.4? I try following

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(EmployeePeer::NAME.' as ename');
$c->addSelectColumn(EmployeePeer::NAME.' as manager');
$c->setPrimaryTableName(EmployeePeer::TABLE_NAME);
$c->addJoin(EmployeePeer::MID, EmployeePeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(EmployeePeer::MID, NULL, Criteria::EQUAL);
```

Even I know this query do not make any sense and as per my expectation, I got PropelException.

But self join is one of the common database operation and I'm sure Propel must support that. Can someone please tell how to achieve above requirements in Symfony/Propel 1.4

Comment: Any possibility of upgrading Propel to version 1.6?

Comment: @RobAgar No. Will be upgraded in future but not now. Right now product is very close to launch so any major change are possible only after launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab752/10), the SQL you want to perform is:

```
SELECT e.name as ename, m.name as manager
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee m ON e.mid = m.id WHERE e.mid IS NOT NULL;
```

Like `YouthPark`, I think `addAlias` is the solution and I will do something like that:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(EmployeePeer::NAME.' as ename');
$c->addSelectColumn(EmployeePeer::NAME.' as manager');

$c->addAlias('c2', EmployeePeer::TABLE_NAME);

$c->addJoin(EmployeePeer::ID, EmployeePeer::alias('c2', EmployeePeer::MID), Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);

$c->add(EmployeePeer::MID, Criteria::ISNOTNULL);
```

I'm not sure about the `addSelectColumn` part, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Well I never tried so not sure if that help you or not but there is no other answers so you might try/further search `addAlias` method, if you are stuck.

```
$notifCrit->addAlias("A", ThreadsPeer::TABLE_NAME);
$notifCrit->add("A.father_id", ThreadsPeer::FATHER_ID."=A.father_id", Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

Taken from last comment of [old symfony forums](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/9590/)

Not sure but Propel 1.4 might not support self join with build in methods as it need to set alias. So you need custom query as in above example.

Comment: Ahh thanks and +1 for help. I also went through forum post you mentioned but seems it is not working for me. May be some other error in my code. Still checking if it works for me or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(ArticlePeer::AUTHOR_ID, AuthorPeer::ID);
$c->add(AuthorPeer::NAME, 'John Doe');
$articles = ArticlePeer::doSelect($c);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!